# Search SQL Server Table Using Simple ASP.NET Search Bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Thank you for taking the time to read my request. I am new to ASP.Net and I am trying to figure out how to implement a textbox/button that will search a SQL Server database and grab results based on queries that are 'like' an attribute. Here is what I have so far...

ASPX Main file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/PantryAdmin.Master"        AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Products.aspx.cs" Inherits="RampantryF.Products" %>
    <asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <script runat="server">
     public string SearchString
     {
         get { return TextBox4.Text;  }
     }
 </script>
   <html>

<head>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        /*Search box*/

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" PostBack="" runat="server" Text="Search" />
    <asp:Label ID="SearchBox" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="Maroon"></asp:Label>
    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PRODUCT_ID" HeaderText="PRODUCT_ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PRODUCT_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UPC_CODE" HeaderText="UPC_CODE" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="UPC_CODE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PRODUCT_NAME" HeaderText="PRODUCT_NAME" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PRODUCT_NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PRODUCT_TYPE" HeaderText="PRODUCT_TYPE" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PRODUCT_TYPE" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RampantryDB %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PRODUCT]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <fieldset>
        <asp:DetailsView
            ID="dtlDonor"
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
            DefaultMode="Insert" Caption="Add Product (C)"

            AutoGenerateRows="False"
            runat="server">
            <Fields>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="PRODUCT_ID" HeaderText="PRODUCT_ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PRODUCT_ID" Visible="False" />




                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UPC_CODE" SortExpression="UPC_CODE">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UPC_CODE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UPC_CODE") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UPC_CODE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PRODUCT_NAME" SortExpression="PRODUCT_NAME">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCT_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRODUCT_NAME") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRODUCT_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PRODUCT_TYPE" SortExpression="PROUDUCT_TYPE">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODUCT_TYPE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRODUCT_TYPE") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PRODUCT_TYPE") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
    </fieldset>

         <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SortParameterName="OrderBy" MaximumRowsParameterName="PageSize" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" SelectMethod="SelectAll" TypeName="RampantryF.App_Code.BLL.PRODUCT" UpdateMethod="Update">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="PRODUCT_ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UPC_CODE" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PRODUCT_NAME" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PRODUCT_TYPE" Type="String" />

        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="PRODUCT_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UPC_CODE" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PRODUCT_NAME" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PRODUCT_TYPE" Type="String" />

        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Behind 'Products.aspx.cs' code file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace RampantryF
{
    public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public SqlConnection con;
        public string constr;



        public void connection()
        {
            constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PRODUCT"].ToString();
            con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();

        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SearchBox.Visible = false;
        }

        private void rep_bind()
        {
            connection();
            string query = "select * from PRODUCT where PRODUCT_NAME like'" + TextBox4.Text + "%'";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection();
            string query = "select PRODUCT_NAME  from PRODUCT where PRODUCT_NAME like'" + TextBox4.Text + "%'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();


            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();

                rep_bind();
                GridView1.Visible = true;

                TextBox4.Text = "";
                SearchBox.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                GridView1.Visible = false;
                SearchBox.Visible = true;
                SearchBox.Text = "The search Term " + TextBox4.Text + " &nbsp;Is Not Available in the Records"; ;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

BLL Products.cs File:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using RampantryF.App_Code.DAL;

namespace RampantryF.App_Code.BLL
{
    public class PRODUCT
{
    private int _PRODUCT_ID;
    private double _UPC_CODE = 0;
    private string _PRODUCT_NAME = String.Empty;
    private string _PRODUCT_TYPE = String.Empty;


    ///Product Unique Identifier
    public int PRODUCT_ID
    {
        get { return _PRODUCT_ID; }
    }

    ///Product UPC_CODE
    ///
    public double UPC_CODE
    {
        get { return _UPC_CODE; }
    }
    ///Product PRODUCT_NAME
    ///
    public string PRODUCT_NAME
    {
        get { return _PRODUCT_NAME; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  Product PRODUCT_TYPE
    /// </summary>
    public string PRODUCT_TYPE
    {
        get { return _PRODUCT_TYPE; }
    }


    ///retrieves all products
    ///
    public static List<PRODUCT> SelectAll()
    {
        DBUtils DBUtils = new DBUtils();
        return DBUtils.PRODUCTSelectAll();
    }
    public static List<PRODUCT> SelectAll(string OrderBy)
    {
        DBUtils DBUtils = new DBUtils();
        return DBUtils.PRODUCTSelectAll(OrderBy);
    }
    ///Updates a particular product
    ///
    public static void Update(int PRODUCT_ID, double UPC_CODE, string PRODUCT_NAME, string PRODUCT_TYPE)
    {
        if (PRODUCT_ID < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Product Id must be greater than 0", "id");

        PRODUCT ProductToUpdate = new PRODUCT(PRODUCT_ID, UPC_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_TYPE);
        ProductToUpdate.Save();
    }
    ///inserts new product
    ///
    public static void Insert(double UPC_CODE, string PRODUCT_NAME, string PRODUCT_TYPE)
    {
        PRODUCT newProduct = new PRODUCT(UPC_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_TYPE);
        newProduct.Save();
    }
    ///Deletes an Existing Product
    ///
    public static void Delete(int PRODUCT_ID)
    {
        if (PRODUCT_ID < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Product Id must be greater than 0", "id");

        DBUtils DBUtils = new DBUtils();
        DBUtils.PRODUCTDelete(PRODUCT_ID);
    }
    ///validates Product information before saving Product
    ///properties to database
    ///
    private void Save()
    {


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_PRODUCT_NAME))
            throw new ArgumentException("Product PRODUCT_NAME not supplied", "PRODUCT_NAME");

        DBUtils DBUtils = new DBUtils();
        if (_PRODUCT_ID > 0)
            DBUtils.PRODUCTUpdate(this);
        else
            DBUtils.PRODUCTInsert(this);

    }
    ///Intializes Product
    ///
    public PRODUCT(int PRODUCT_ID, double UPC_CODE, string PRODUCT_NAME, string PRODUCT_TYPE)
    {
        _PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT_ID;
        _UPC_CODE = UPC_CODE;
        _PRODUCT_NAME = PRODUCT_NAME;
        _PRODUCT_TYPE = PRODUCT_TYPE;

    }
    public PRODUCT(double UPC_CODE, string PRODUCT_NAME, string PRODUCT_TYPE)
    {
        _UPC_CODE = UPC_CODE;
        _PRODUCT_NAME = PRODUCT_NAME;
        _PRODUCT_TYPE = PRODUCT_TYPE;

    }


}
}
```

Any help anyone can provide is very much appreciated! Again, I am new to this, and I have been following tutorials and googling the internet trying to find a solution but cannot find one.

As of now, the page loads, but it will not actually search when the button is clicked. I would like it to change the GridView1 with all of the records into records that fill into a 'LIKE Textbox4' query.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add click event to your search button like `OnClick="Button1_Click"`

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" PostBack="" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click"  />
```

also note that, inside button click event again you are calling another method to bind data to same gridview. You will lost what ever you have bind in the click event from this second method.